# What's the meaning of "benign ass a lone chocolate chip" in the sentence

Tags: phrase-usage

I bumped into this sentence in a web post. I am wondering how "**benign ass a lone chocolate chip**" works here? I searched 'benign ass' on the web, but no luck.  Can someone help to explain?

> It could be something as **benign ass a lone chocolate chip** in your vanilla ice cream.

Comment: *As*, not *ass*.  "**As benign as** a lone chocolate chip".   The "as X as a ..." structure is fairly basic English.  Funny, though.

Comment: So, it's a typo then. :(

Comment: Yes, but the funny part is that there is actually a slang where you can call something an (adjective)-ass (noun), e.g. "I'm a grown-ass man!"  At first I thought that's what this sentence was saying (a *benign-ass chocolate chip*) until I read it more carefully.  The "ass" part of this slang doesn't mean anything, it's just a bit of vulgarity used for emphasis.

Comment: At least, now I learnt the slang (adjective)-ass. Does a grown-ass man mean an adult bad guy?

Comment: No, it's just a way of saying "I'm a grown man!" (meaning "I'm an adult, not a child") but with extra emphasis.  Similarly "That's a stupid-ass idea" means "that's a really stupid idea".  I'm not sure how common it is outside of the United States, though.